# Using =IMPORTXML in Google Spreadsheets to extract a table by descriptions

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

From the website http://www.findagrave.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi?page=gr&GScid=97961&GRid=22682396 I am trying to extract just the text data such as,  birth, death, bio, location, and the created by sections into different rows/columns. I want to be able to have a spreadsheet where I can input a FindAGrave URL and have it extract the above data for me. I read here [Using =importXML in Google Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360217/using-importxml-in-google-docs) that its possible to do it by descriptions. From there I learned to omit the Xpath tbody. That successfully got my import to work, but without using the descriptions. I'm sure if using descriptions would be more efficient or not. I just want to learn how other people would go about importing data from tables.
Thanks

Here is what I got so far. This will extract the Birth information and put in rows. One problem is that it adds an extra cell in between each data.

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.findagrave.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi?page=gr&GScid=97961&GRid=22682396", "//html/body/table/tr/td[3]/table/tr[4]/td[1]/table/tr/td/table/tr/td/table/tr[1]/td[2]")
```

Result

```
Dec. 2, 1882        Humphreys County        Tennessee, USA
```

Update: I think I made some process along in the code. This is what I'm working with now.

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.findagrave.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi?page=gr&GScid=97961&GRid=22682396", "//*[@class='gr'][1]//tr/td/table/tr/td/table/tr[1]/td[1]")
=IMPORTXML("http://www.findagrave.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi?page=gr&GScid=97961&GRid=22682396", "//*[@class='gr']//tr/td/table/tr/td/table/tr[1]/td[2]/text()[1]")
=IMPORTXML("http://www.findagrave.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi?page=gr&GScid=97961&GRid=22682396", "//*[@class='gr']//tr/td/table/tr/td/table/tr[1]/td[2]/text()[2]")
=IMPORTXML("http://www.findagrave.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi?page=gr&GScid=97961&GRid=22682396", "//*[@class='gr']//tr/td/table/tr/td/table/tr[1]/td[2]/text()[3]")
=IMPORTXML("http://www.findagrave.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi?page=gr&GScid=97961&GRid=22682396", "//*[@class='gr']//tr/td/table/tr/td/table/tr[1]/td[2]/text()[4]")

=IMPORTXML("http://www.findagrave.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi?page=gr&GScid=97961&GRid=22682396", "//*[@class='gr'][1]//tr/td/table/tr/td/table/tr[2]/td[1]")
=IMPORTXML("http://www.findagrave.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi?page=gr&GScid=97961&GRid=22682396", "//*[@class='gr']//tr/td/table/tr/td/table/tr[2]/td[2]/text()[1]")
=IMPORTXML("http://www.findagrave.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi?page=gr&GScid=97961&GRid=22682396", "//*[@class='gr']//tr/td/table/tr/td/table/tr[2]/td[2]/text()[2]")
=IMPORTXML("http://www.findagrave.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi?page=gr&GScid=97961&GRid=22682396", "//*[@class='gr']//tr/td/table/tr/td/table/tr[2]/td[2]/text()[3]")
=IMPORTXML("http://www.findagrave.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi?page=gr&GScid=97961&GRid=22682396", "//*[@class='gr']//tr/td/table/tr/td/table/tr[2]/td[2]/text()[4]")
```

Results:

```
Birth: 
Nov. 8, 1948
Benton
Saline County
Arkansas, USA

Death: 
Jan. 6, 2006
Tulsa
Tulsa County
Oklahoma, USA
```

Is there a way to split this data up within the code?

Answer (score 3):

The following formula

```
=IMPORTXML(
"http://www.findagrave.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi?page=gr&GScid=97961&GRid=22682396",
"//html/body/table/tr/td[3]/table/tr[4]/td[1]/table/tr/td/table/tr/td/table/tr[position()<=2]/td/text()"
)
```

returns

```
Birth: 
Nov. 8, 1948
Benton
Saline County
Arkansas, USA
Death: 
Jan. 6, 2006
Tulsa
Tulsa County
Oklahoma, USA
```

A shorter alternative,

```
=IMPORTXML(
"http://www.findagrave.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi?page=gr&GScid=97961&GRid=22682396", 
"//tr[4]/td[1]//tr[position()<=2]/td/text()"
)
```

returns the same result

Answer (score 1):

You can get multiple fields by simplifying your xpaths - you can also add multiple into one single function call separating the xpaths with a `|` :

```
`=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML($A3,"//td[@align='left']/text()|//tr[6]/td/a|//tr[3]/td/text()[1]"))))`
```

[image]

The three xpaths used are:

`//td[@align='left']/text()`

`//tr[6]/td/a`

`//tr[3]/td/text()[1]`